# Compare Two Arrays That include a Dictionary and an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, arraylist, comparison

I have the following array that contains a searched product by the user; once searched, the tags of the product is also stored in the searchTags array like below:

```
searchedTags = [ [product : [tagA, tagB, tagC, tagD, tagH ]] ]
```

Now I have a array list of all products that contains different tags for each product:

```
productTagsArray = [ [product1 : [tagA, tagB, tagC, tagD]],
                [product2 : [tagC, tagD, tagE, tagF, tag H]], 
                [product3 : [tagH, tagI, tagJ]],
                [product4 : [tagK, tagL, tagM]],
                ...
              ]
```

Now I would like to check and compare the tags from the searched product in `searchedTags` with each product in `productTagsArray`. Once compared, I'd like to make a new array of products sorted by the COUNTS of tags matched (high to low) with the searched products. If there are no tags matching I do not want to include them in the new variable. I would like to populate the result of this sorted match like below:

```
sortedProductsByCount = [[productId : product1, numberOfTagsMatched : 4],
                        [productId : product2, numberOfTagsMatched : 2],
                        [productId : product1, numberOfTagsMatched : 1]
                        ]
```

**Edit:**
This is what I have written for when the user click on the search result in tableview:

```
var productsTagCount: [[String:Any]] = [[:]]

    for tags in searchedProductTags {
        for tag in tags {
            for productArray in productTagsArray {
                for product in productArray {

                    var tagCount: Int = 0

                    for productTag in product.value {
                        if productTag == tag {
                            tagCount = tagCount + 1
                        }
                    }

                    let data: [String : Any] = [
                        "productId": product.key,
                        "tagCount": tagCount
                    ]

                    productsTagCount.append(data)

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way? How can I accomplish the `sortedProductByCount` array?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried doing `for  tag in productTags.values` and in that I did another `for tag in searchedTags.values` and tried to match one by one then add to an array and count but it didnt seem right or work. I am not sure how to go about it as I am quite a newbie here as well. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I just edited my question with what I tried; is that the right approach? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I took a look at the posted code but there are collections not mentioned elsewhere in the question and it is hard to understand what the content is in all the collections, both keys and values so I gave up.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for trying. I figured out a solution and had to change some of my codings; posting what I ended up her in case it can be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it. Had to change my codes quite a bit.

```
var productTagsArray : [[String : [String]]] = [[:]]
var productTagCount : [String : Int] = [:]
var sortedProductTagCount: [Int : [String : Int]] = [:]


let searchedProductTags = searchResults[indexPath.row].values

    for productArray in productTagsArray {
        for product in productArray {

            let productId: String = product.key
            var tagCount: Int = 0

            for productTag in product.value {

                for searchedTags in searchedProductTags {
                    for searchedTag in searchedTags {

                        if productTag == searchedTag {
                            tagCount = tagCount + 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if tagCount != 0 {                    
                productTagCount[productId] = tagCount                    
            }
        }
    }

    //Make an array with sorted tagscount
    let sortedProductTagCountVar = productTagCount.sorted{ $0.value > $1.value }
    var productSortIndex: Int = 0

    for (k,v) in sortedProductTagCountVar {
        productSortIndex = productSortIndex + 1
        sortedProductTagCount[productSortIndex, default: [:]][k] = v
    }
```